# what is a proper circuit for RF switch matrix in microwave frequencies?

Tags: rf, switches, integrated-circuit, analog, circuit-design

I am going to make an RF circuit that can switch between multiple RF ports in microwave band like an MxN  simplex switching matrix. Generally I don't know if this would be possible in analog domain as digital domain with high switching rate and low distortion?

To be clear, what is the typical switching rate that is achievable in RF/Analog domain when we wish to implement this by basic elements in discrete form? 
secondly, is there any good electrical circuit scheme form band 2Gig or more that can work in discrete circuit ?

assume we have 10 receiving antenna to be switched to 12 band pass filters at 2Ghz and 250Mhz bandwidth. 
the required insertion loss is less than 6 db and the leakage from irrelevant ports should be less than -40db.

Comment: Look up PIN diodes and when someone does give you a good answer it might be cool to formally accept it. You can practice on your earlier questions if you feel so inclined.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? Are you sure that an MxN matrix switch is the best solution?

Comment: @andy, i didnt get your comment, why should i look up PIN diode?

Comment: @photon, the problem is to switch between multiple antenna feed/LNA to filter bank for re-configurable RF suit.

Comment: Well if you "loop up" a PIN diode I'd be confused.

Comment: @behradmahboobi  your specs are weak at best, without which no one can choose. 1ns pin diode switch time is possible and so are thousands of others.

Comment: @TonyStewart pin diode a proper technology for fast switching, but I am looking for an electrical circuit that can address the switching matrix functionality in analog (RF) domain.

Comment: ok but no one can choose unless you have spec'd criteria  e.g. 64 antenna MIMO with 20MHz BW <1dB loss

Comment: ok i will specify a sample spec.

Comment: duplex simplex?

Comment: simplex is enough (will be fixed in the question)

Answer (score 2):

There are many choices now, but the most cost-effective is GaN on SiC, while faster chips can use Diamond substrate.($)

These about the size of a grain of rice and can switch up to 6GHz at 20MHz rate.

[image]

```
Frequency Range: 0.5 - 6 GHz
• Insertion Loss: ≤ 0.8 dB
• Power Handling: 46 dBm (P.1dB)
• Return Loss: > 15 dB
• Isolation: > 26 dB
• Control Voltages: 0 V/-40 V (from either side of the
MMIC)
• Switching Speed: < 50 ns
• Reflective Switch
• Die Dimensions: 1.397 mm x 1.580 mm x 0.10 mm

The TriQuint TGS2354 is a Single-Pole, Double-Throw
(SPDT) reflective switch fabricated on TriQuint's
TQGaN25 0.25um GaN on SiC production process.
Operating from 0.5 to 6GHz, the TGS2354 typically
supports up to 40W input power handling at control
voltages of 0/-40 V. This switch maintains low insertion
loss of 0.8 dB or less, and greater than 25dB isolation
making it ideal for high power switching applications
across both defense and commercial platforms..
The TGS2354 is available in a small 1.397 x 1.58 mm
die size and allows control voltage input from either side
of the die. This, along with the minimal DC power
consumption, allows for easy system integration.
```

Comment: @stewart, i am mostly looking for a circuit that work for analog switching. not the technology behind its implementation.

Comment: @ Mr Mahboobi have not even searched / looked at the data sheet TGS2354

Comment: i reviewed the datasheet, however the circuit offered by a microstrip without circuit equivalent, it was also 3 port switch which wasn't also generalizable to MxN case.

Comment: Control voltage - 40v ?

Comment: yes -40V for lowest compression and capacitance